# Returning String with Express post

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this *app.js* file:

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express()
let Clarifai = require('clarifai')

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static('./public'))
let link = app.post('/route', (req, res) => {
    let linkString = req.body.link
    res.send(JSON.stringify(linkString))
})

app.listen(3000)

const capp = new Clarifai.App({
    apiKey: 'MyAPIKeyIsHere'
   });

predict = capp.models.initModel({id: Clarifai.FOOD_MODEL, version: "aa7f35c01e0642fda5cf400f543e7c40"})
      .then(generalModel => {
        return generalModel.predict(link)
      })
      .then(response => {
        var concepts = response['outputs'][0]['data']['concepts']
        console.log(concepts)
})

console.log('Express app running on port 3000')
console.log(link)
```

I am trying to return a string from the `app.post` method but it returns a *JSON* file. How should I do it exactly?

Answer (score 20):

You can explicitly set the content type to text/html, before sending the data.

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.send(JSON.stringify(linkString));
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `req.body.link` is a `string`? If yes you could just pass `linkString` variable in `send`:

```
 let link = app.post('/route', (req, res) => {
    let linkString = req.body.link
    res.send(linkString)
})
```

Comment: Yes, req.body.link will return the text that I input into it. I have tried just putting linkString into res.send but it returns a JSON object.